# Is there a law that prohibits one from creating an avatar that looks exactly like someone else?

Tags: copyright, online

Let's say I'm playing some video game like [Second Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Life) where players create an avatar in a virtual world. These games usually allow players to customize their avatar's appearance.

Is there some law that prohibits me from making my avatar look like someone else? Can I, for example, create an avatar that looks like some famous politician and then do a lot of obnoxious things in-game to smear that politician's name?

I'm tagging the question with 'copyright' because I'm guessing that if it's illegal, it has something to do with copyrighting depictions of oneself.

Comment: IANL - "smear that politician's name" sounds like *defamation* - which *may* get you into far more legal or financial trouble than the avatar itself.

Comment: You can't copyright your appearance.  A particular depiction of a person (eg, a 3d model) can have copyright, usually by the person who created it.  There might be some consideration for for _publicity_ or likeness rights if you weren't authorized by the actual person; however if you're attempting to deceive others that you are that person it's more likely that you're looking at fraud or similar.  Note that, especially for politicians, you _can_ impersonate somebody for satire or parody reasons, or other commentary reasons (such as when an actor portrays a real person in a documentary).